# Requesting a Rubik's Cubing site

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

I was wondering if anybody else wanted to create a Stack Exchange site on Cubing.

Comment: Such requests belong to http://area51.stackexchange.com I love rubik's but what sort of questions would I ask about it? nothing to be asked

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because new site creation requests belong to area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SPArchaeologist while essentially correct, there is whole faq about how to propose a new site, so such questions are just duplicates of that. I didn't close it myself only because such a site already exists, so this question has no real point. (e.g. like requesting a site for programming or cooking.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I somehow fail to see the benefit of marking this as a dupe and not just off-topic, but if that is the preferred procedure, no problem.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist well, it was Adam's decision in this case. But generally speaking, question suggesting to propose a new site is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not necessary - questions about Rubik's Cubes are on-topic on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) (if reasonably scoped, of course). They already have 75 questions tagged [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube) at the moment of writing this post.

Otherwise, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go to create new communities.

Comment: "Otherwise, Area 51 is the place to go to create new communities." Technically it's the place to create a Q&A for an already existing community. See [this answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28128/118891) and [this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20966/118891) by Cartaino.

Comment: @Mast that was a new policy introduced in 2018. I'd update my answer if it weren't for the possibility that it might get shut down altogether now that Robert was fired.

Comment: Fair enough. As for the risk of closure, 2 days ago there was no indication of that by [Tim Post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29982/118891). We'll have to see how that pans out.

Comment: 4 days ago there was no indication of the firings :)